# convert Bytes into Gigabytes with javascript math

Tags: javascript, byte, filesize

My web application allows users to upload files. I am able to find the size of these files in bytes. However I need to convert this number to gigabytes with javascript on the back-end. Does anyone know the formula and how to execute this task with javascript ?

For example: right now my file size is 626581571 bytes.

Comment: The value you gave is only 597.55MB. Do you want that to be displayed as a gb value?

Comment: @jeff : The value he gave is `626.58 MB`, or `597.55 MiB`. :)

Comment: @Yuriko, OS (windows at least) use the value of 1024 bytes not the faux 1000 that seems to have crept into the industry.

Comment: @jeff, "kilo-" has always been "a thousand". Kilometer = 1000 meters. Kilogram = 1000 grams. So the "faux" 1000 is not faux at all. Thinking "kilo-" changes its meaning to 1024 when it comes to bytes is just ignorance or stupidity.

Answer (score 8):

1 kilobyte = 1024 bytes, 1 megabyte = 1024 kilobytes, 1 gigabyte = 1024 megabytes, respectively `file_size_gb = 626581571 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024`.

Or as said in the comment below, `file_size_gb = 626581571 / Math.pow(1024, 3)`

Comment: Or `var file_size_gb = 626581571 / Math.pow(1024, 3)`

Comment: Actually, depending on the system and manufacturer, it might be 1000 and not 1024 (but both could be possible)

Comment: He asked for *Gigabytes* (GB) and not *Gigibytes* (GiB).

Answer (score 7):

### 1 KB = 1000 Bytes

It's basic math:

```
1 GB = 1 000 MB = 1 000 000 KB = 1 000 000 000 B

626 581 571 B = 0.626 GB
```

Thus, you just need to divide by 10<sup>9</sup>

```
function byteToGigaByte(n) {
    return  (n / Math.pow(10,9));
}
```

---

### 1 K*i*B = 1024 Bytes

Perhaps you meant [*gibibyte*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte) instead of gigabyte?

Once again, it's basic math:

```
1 GiB = 1024 MiB = 1024 * 1024 KiB = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 B
      = 1073741824 B

626 581 571 B = 0.583 GiB
```

This time, you need to divide by 2<sup>30</sup>

```
function byteToGibiByte(n) {
    return  (n / Math.pow(2,30));
}
```

*Note the slight difference between gigabyte and gibibyte: `1 GB = 0.931 GiB`.*